# Event.Listener is not working for socket.io in android

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, socket.io, eventemitter

I'm trying to listen to an event from server using socket.io through node js server in my android client app. But it is not returning any response in android app.

I've tried various things but it is not helping. What I am trying to do is to listen to requestedTrip event but it doesn't listen to it.

```
Java Code (Android): 
On Create(){
socket.on("requestedTrip", handleTripRequests);
}
 private Emitter.Listener handleTripRequests = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    passengerPhone = data.getString("userPhone");
                    passengerOriginLat = data.getString("location_latitude");
                    passengerOriginLng = data.getString("location_longitude");
                    passengerDestLat = data.getString("destination_latitude");
                    passengerDestLng = data.getString("destination_longitude");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    };
Node js:

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
socket.on('online',async (name,phone,latitude,longitude)=>{
    const onlineUsers = new OnlineUsers();
    onlineUsers.phone = phone;
    onlineUsers.longitude = longitude;
    onlineUsers.latitude = latitude;
    await onlineUsers.save();
    username = name;
    userphone = phone;
    console.log(name+" is online");

})


    var data;
socket.on('requestTrip',async (p_userphone, p_originLat, p_originLng, p_destLat,p_destLng,status)=>{
    const pendingTrips = new PendingTrip();
    pendingTrips.userPhone = p_userphone;
    pendingTrips.location_longitude = p_originLng;
    pendingTrips.location_latitude = p_originLat;
    pendingTrips.destination_longitude = p_destLng;
    pendingTrips.destination_latitude = p_destLat;

    pg_userphone = p_userphone;
    pg_originLat = p_originLat;
    pg_originLng = p_originLng;
    pg_destLat = p_destLat;
    pg_destLng = p_destLng;


 data = {
        "userPhone": pg_userphone,
        "location_latitude": pg_originLat,
        "location_longitude": pg_originLng,
        "destination_latitude": pg_destLat,
        "destination_longitude": pg_destLng
    };
    socket.emit('requestedTrip',{
        "userPhone": pg_userphone,
        "location_latitude": pg_originLat,
        "location_longitude": pg_originLng,
        "destination_latitude": pg_destLat,
        "destination_longitude": pg_destLng
    });



    pendingTrips.status = status;
    await pendingTrips.save();
    console.log(pg_userphone+"  "+pg_destLat)
    console.log(data);

})







socket.on('disconnect',async ()=>{
    const onlineUsers = await OnlineUsers.deleteMany({
        phone: userphone
    });
    console.log(username+" is offline");

})
```

})

I expect it to show the JSON response in the form of toast but it is not displaying anything.

Comment: consider java syntax to be correct

Comment: Where is your `connect` called from? `onStart`?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir connect is called in  `onCreate`